# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bootstrap5' getting this error after moving my django project to docker

Tags: django, docker, dockerfile, django-bootstrap5

Hi I just moved my Django project on the docker. And created an image successfully.
But when,I tried running it using

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 my-django-app
```

I am getting the error

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run      
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 398, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 193, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1142, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bootstrap5'
```

I have even added the bootstrap5 in the django settings

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'firstapp',
    'bootstrap5',
]
```

And I have added it in the requriments.txt

```
django-bootstrap5==23.3
```

This if my dockerfile

```
# Use an official Python runtime as the base image
FROM python:3.11.1

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the requirements.txt file and install the Python dependencies
COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy the rest of the application code
COPY . /app/

# Expose the port the Django application will run on
EXPOSE 8000

# Set the command to start the Django development server
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

I have installed it using

```
pip install django-bootstrap-v5
```

I checked the version of the bootstrap5 as well as the settings.py but everything seems fine. I am trying to move this existing django project on the docker.

Answer (score 0):

[django-bootstrap5](https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap5/) and [django-bootstrap-v5](https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap-v5/) these are different packages. And which is using different app names as well.

In your case you have installed `django-bootstrap-v5` but in the `requirements.txt` you mentioned `django-bootstrap5==23.3`.

You need to updated it as `django-bootstrap-v5==1.0.11`.

Use this command to generate `requirements.txt` with lists of all the dependencies.

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

**Note** : Adding/updating the requirements.txt manually is generally not recommended. It may leads to inconsistencies in the package versions. Instead it is best to generate it automatically.